# Logistic Regression classifier works well during cross validation but fails on production data. Any suggestions why?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, cross-validation

I generated a Logistic Regression classifier and tested it using k (10) fold cross validation. 
The Accuracy was about 81.8 and confusion matrix showed acceptable results on both classes (A& B):

```
   Recall:              Precision:
a: 0.4157303370786517   0.578125
b: 0.9215876089060987   0.8592057761732852
```

Before deploying the model to production I generated an overall version (based on the whole training set without cross validation) and tested it on the production data gap (from the time we took the training data until now). The thing is results now were horrible - accuracy of about 79.6 and classification that was almost totally biased to one side, see the confusion matrix -

```
    Recall:                Precision:
a:  0.013245033112582781   0.4444444444444444
b:  0.995777027027027      0.7982396750169262
```

Any suggestions why it can happen?

Comment: Lots of slips twixt the lip and the cup. Check, check and recheck that the implementation wasn't flawed somehow. If any of the features were transformed, ensure that there is a one-to-one correspondence between how the ad hoc work was done and its translation to the production environment. Usually, it's something really small and simple.

Comment: The accuracy measures you chose have too much arbitrariness and are low precision improper accuracy scoring rules.  They will mislead you at every step.  Concentrate on proper accuracy scores (e.g. Brier score) and semi-proper ones ($c$-index = AUROC) plus smooth calibration curves.

Comment: How did you draw your training sample? Did you use stratification? Are your sub-sample groups comparable to your sub-population groups?

Comment: Even if the implementation is consistent with how the model was trained, you must consider the possibility that your phenomenon of interest is a moving target, and whether/how to properly account for the time-series nature of your data.